# set max sdk version on build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

How set the android max sdk version on build.gradle at android studio.

I want do an app with two flavor, the first will run between version x~y and the second run at y+

Before on eclipse, in AndroidManifest.xml we have `android:maxSdkVersion="y"` but how it works on gradle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set the `maxSdkVersion` in gradle. Actually, it is discourage by Google because of several issues. The main issue is that Google Play could decide to remove an app from a user device during an update if the system doesn't meet the `maxSdkVersion` specified in the app. For example, imagine you have a device with API Level 12 and you install an app with `android:maxSdkVersion="12"`, then later you receive a system update that upgrades your android version to API Level 13...Google Play will uninstall your app.

Basically, you don't need this setting and you can easily ignore it, use the `targetSDkVersion` attribute and the `minSdkVersion`.

1. For your app "in flavour 1" with "version x~y" set the `minSdkversion` to x and the `targetSdkVersion` to y
2. now, for the app "in flavour 2", you will need to make sure that the sdk version don't get overlapped by the app "in flavour 1", set the min sdk version to "z". Otherwise, users with a device with api level "y" will never get to see this app in Google Play

Comment: Wrong answer. You can set `maxSdkVersion ` and sometimes it is needed, see why https://stackoverflow.com/a/70798421/3826175

Comment: Did you realize this question was about android studio + gradle? Those sdk tags in manifest.xml are ignored and overriden by gradle. This 10-year-old answer is still valid. `maxSdkVersion` **is not a thing in gradle**. Do some research before confusing people with wild claims

Answer (score 2):

Please note this.

Future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or re-validation. Google Play will continue to use the attribute as a filter, however, when presenting users with applications available for download.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

I think accepted answer is not correct.  Accepted answer says it is not possible to set maxSdkVersion - it is not true. It is still possible to use maxSdkVersion in android studio app/build.gradle. As described here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element developer must notice warning and should understand why wants to do it. Nobody here take care that in play store you can provide several bundles/packages at once (per update/release) and one bundle can be targeted for new devices and another for old devices so it is fine second one limit by maxSdkVersion. One app bundle have versionCode e.g. 2xyz and for older devices is versionCode 1xyz and google always installs higher code when minSdkVersion allows it. So developer can purposely set maxSdkVersion and he know why hi is doing it.

Each our app update have 2 packages with different app/build.gradle...

**For old devices**
(maxSdkVersion has sense here)

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    maxSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1058
    versionName "4.4.0"
}
```

**For new devices**
(without limiting maxSdkVersion as googole warns that should not be used)

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 2058
    versionName "4.4.0"
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, sorry. Question was about android studio + gradle. In gradle, `maxSdkVersion` doesn't even exist. Plus the link you've provided refers to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Not only wrong but also confusing

Comment: @Leo You are wrong. I have today added maxSdkVersion in android studio, created bundle and successfully published in store - proof here: https://i.ibb.co/JKvL02H/01.png Sources codes above are from android studio from app/build.gradle file as I wrote in answer. Why maxSdkVersion should be not orking when here is no mention https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element it is removed - there just warning and its usage in some cases is needed.

Comment: Proof number 2: https://i.ibb.co/SwJ0s7R/01.png

Comment: you are taking a massive risk by using unsupported/undocumented features. This could be removed by Google at any point. Again, the values in manifest are ignored in Android studio. And in Gradle, this has been marked obsolete AND removed completely in latest versions. Just because it works, doesn't mean is the correct approach

Comment: By this google UI https://i.ibb.co/JKvL02H/01.png google takes it into account